# MongoDB auth error during deployment, no errors while running locally

Tags: mongodb

Getting the following error during deployment:

```
5:30:38 PM: [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
5:30:39 PM: Server listening on http://localhost:3000
5:30:39 PM: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202
5:30:39 PM:                 callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
5:30:39 PM:                          ^
5:30:39 PM: MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
5:30:39 PM:     at Connection.onMessage (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202:26)
5:30:39 PM:     at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
5:30:39 PM:     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
5:30:39 PM:     at processIncomingData (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:124:16)
5:30:39 PM:     at MessageStream._write (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
5:30:39 PM:     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
5:30:39 PM:     at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
5:30:39 PM:     at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
5:30:39 PM:     at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:809:22)
5:30:39 PM:     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28) {
5:30:39 PM:   ok: 0,
5:30:39 PM:   code: 8000,
5:30:39 PM:   codeName: "AtlasError",
5:30:39 PM:   connectionGeneration: 0,
5:30:39 PM:   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { "HandshakeError", "ResetPool" }
5:30:39 PM: }
```

I've been through a million different iterations and Stackoverflow replies. The username is fine and the user is outfitted with admin rights on Mongo, the password has been triple checked and as stated, works in local. This is exclusively a problem that arises during deployment. Help?

Comment: Does your password contain any special characters?

Comment: None, I've weeded out all of those problems, same with the carrots <>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During deployment I had forgotten to account for the .env file. Adding environment variables to the deployment server settings solved the problem.